My entire balance is gone. Please let me know if it is an error or a hack
I installed the phantom wallet and sent sol. And I could use it more conveniently if I created a user name, so I made user name and synchronized it. and all the existing sol disappeared. When I checked the scan, it was transferred to another wallet.
